# Redis Cache With Django Rest Framework Testing

Tags: testing, caching, django-rest-framework, redis

In my current project I have some code that requires caching (I use Redis for now).And for that reason I can't use fake cache or mock. And through the tests I need a clean cache, so at `setup` of test case class I use the following:

```py
from django_redis import get_redis_connection
get_redis_connection("default").flushall()
```

Which breaks the parallel testing(and can make race condition).
What's the best practice of testing with active caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who passes by, I've changed the cache backend to `LocMemCache` when testing. After that, caches aren't affected by parallel testing anymore.

Something like this:

```py
TESTING = 'test' in sys.argv
if TESTING:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        }
    }
else:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
            'LOCATION': REDIS_HOST,
        }
    }
```

**Caution:** some operations which are supported by `RedisCache`, aren't supported by `LocMemCache`. `cache.ttl()` is an example.